How to enable javascript LSP inside html script tags?
Is there a neovim plugin or a custom configuration of the html LSP that could allow to have linting in html/templ script tags using tsserver or eslint ?
<script>
  // I want tsserver to lint this part of the code
</script>


I am not a neovim user but https://github.com/BenoitZugmeyer/eslint-plugin-html looks something that can be used with eslint.

Also consider checking this SO question

@sylasov Thank you, eslint-plugin-html seems to be the way to go

@VladyslavShlianin Thank you, in the post it comes down to eslint-plugin-html as mentionned by sylasov

If you don't mind, you may write an answer to this question with your solutions. This way your post will be helpful for other people

eslint-plugin-html does that .
